# PHP managing forgot password

Tags: php, mysql, web, forgot-password

I'm working on a forgot password page and trying to figure out the best way to do it. Currently, when a user goes to the page it asks for their email. The script checks if the account exists, and sends them an email with a link to click to reset their password.

The link contains a token (which is just `md5(uniqid())`) and the email address to match to the database when the user chooses a new password. It stores the token in a database table `password_resets` along with an expiration date of 24hrs from now and a foreign key to their account details.

When the user chooses a new password it matches the token to the `password_resets` table, the email to that foreign key's email address, and makes sure the expiration date is in the future before setting the new password and deleting the record from `password_resets`.

Is this an efficient way of doing it? It almost seems redundant to have a whole table for this purpose. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It is efficient, you should not have any problems. Just make a cron script to flush obsolete tokens. Alternatively you can use JWT token implementation which would eliminate the need for any database.

Comment: A bit off-topic but `uniqid()`  [does not generate cryptographically secure values](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) so you should consider using an alternative random function such as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

Comment: @this.lau_ their use of `md5(uniqid())` isn't uniquely using `uniqid()` and has nothing to do with cryptography, it's only to be used as a unique token which is perfectly well-suited. What they fail to mention or may not know about, is using a safe (password) hashing function such as `password_hash()`. I think the question goes beyond what they posted. So yeah, a tad off-topic ;-) also `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` may not be available to use on their server.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good point. Just to clarify, I am using `password_hash()` for the passwords.

Comment: @Tomjr260 To answer this: I don't see anything wrong (the logic) in what you want to do. It's a method that is (still) widely used. If you think that the extra work is worth it, then it is ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually i would recommend the same method but i noticed that you wrote on an efficient way for the same. There can be one actually.I am using the [following](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library

```
<?php
    # $key is super secret
    $key = "someRandomKey";
    function gen_token($email,$username) {
        $token = array(
            "email" => $email,
            "username" => $username,
            "created" => time()
        );
        return JWT::encode($token, $key);
    }

    function validate_token($token,$newPassword) {
        # Step below only works on valid token generates on your server
        $data = (array) JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
        $currentTime = time();
        # Validate difference between $currentTime and $data["created"]
        # If time valid update password
    }
?>
```

This method would reduce database latency considerably and also gives you the option to store some validation data on token itself.